# Exporting or creating PDF/X-1a:2001 PDF file using TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

Does anyone know how to export PDF/X-1a:2001 PDF file using PHP [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) library. I researched a lot but could not find a solution. Someone please advise. The solution needs to be in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on TCPDF, but the docs you linked to give a few example code blocks, and most end with a call to the output function. https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_001/

```
$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: This outputs a PDF/A formatted file, not a PDF/X-1a formatted file.

Comment: Then perhaps the documentation for the Output class would be helpful: https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tc-lib-pdf/class-Com.Tecnick.Pdf.Output/ I'm looking specifically at the getOutputIntentsPdfX function (scroll down about halfway), which may do what you're looking for. Like I said, I'm no expert, I've only used TCPDF a few times, so sorry I couldn't be more helpful!

Comment: Yes, there is no clear info about the purpose of these functions. However, from my understanding that only gets the output intent information it does not set it. It is a bit strange though that the description of `getOutputIntents()` is `Set OutputIntents`.

Comment: @kojow7 I believe that's just a typo. Looking at the source code, there's no params for that function and it only returns a string. https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tc-lib-pdf/source-class-Com.Tecnick.Pdf.Output/#236-252 Looking further, there's a getOutXObjects function, but it's blank and left TODO. https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tc-lib-pdf/source-class-Com.Tecnick.Pdf.Output/#492-501 Considering this package is very slowly maintained, I wouldn't count on this functionality for a while unless you implement it yourself.